# How to use magic wand where there is white in the image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, background-removal

I am editing product images so that the background is transparent, the background is currently white.

When I use the magic wand tool it also cuts out the bottle cap of the product because the bottle cap is white. To get around this I duplicated the layer, converted to smart object, made adjustments to the levels so that the bottle cap was no longer white and then used the magic wand tool. After I do this, I go back to the original layer, unlock it, hit delete and then delete the duplicate layer so that the background disappears.

This seems to work but is very time-consuming and trial and error with adjusting the levels.

Is there a simpler way? I am very new to PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic wand tool is by far the simplest way to do this. If the bottle cap is white but slightly different in color from the background (which it seems like it is, if you got it to work using levels), you can try changing the tolerance of the magic wand tool. The lower the tolerance, the more sensitive it is to subtle color changes.

[image]

If you're using version CS6 or above, the tolerance should be in the options bar right under the menu bar. I'm not sure about earlier versions.

So try selecting around the bottle cap first with a low tolerance, and delete that part. Then continue with the rest of the background, setting a higher tolerance.

Note that you can hold Shift and click to add to your selection or Alt/Option to subtract from the selection.

Answer (score 0):

ys.. u can also use

select > color range..

other than magic wand..

[image]

bt if u wanna use only magigwand.. best answer is above